# Ignore node_modules but not some in flowtype

Tags: flowtype

I want to ignore the whole node_modules in my .flowconfig [ignore] section for performance sake, but include some directory I used, like 'react'.

Any one how to do that?

I basically want to ignore all the dev dependency node_modules that affect the `flow check` cli.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

so I still couldn't figure out how to do it.

But instead, I ignore the whole node_modules dir, and use flow-typed to generate some type definition for me. Therefore flowbin will not look into node_modules (and save time), it just look at the definitions flow-typed generated.

ps: Many libs are not found in flow-typed, so they generate `any` type. Thats fine for me, what I really focus to type is my own code.

Comment: flow-typed will not generate definitions for packages that have "*.flow" files in them. This approach will fail in these cases. See this: https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/issues/393